# Custom fields in logger with SpringBoot and JsonLayout

Tags: spring-boot, logging

once I override the addCustomDataToJsonMap() method of JsonLayout how can I use that to set custom flields
I have added below code

```
@Setter
public class CustomLoggingConfig extends JsonLayout {
    public static final String ADDITIONAL_INFO = "additionalInfo";
    private String additionalInfo;
    @Override
    public void addCustomDataToJsonMap(Map<String, Object> var1, ILoggingEvent var2) {
        var1.put(ADDITIONAL_INFO, additionalInfo);
    }
}
```

and my logs are displayed like this:

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2022-08-08 16:48:29.491",
  "level" : "ERROR",
  "thread" : "main",
  "logger" : "jsonLogger",
  "message" : "Exception occurred with message: Error in connecting to database",
  "context" : "default",
  "additionalInfo" : null
}
```

Question is how can I set additionalInfo?